# Copy part of vector of characters to string

Tags: c++

What's the best way to copy part of vector of `char` to a `std::string`? I need only to copy the 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> characters to this string.

```
std::vector<char> stringVector = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
std::string textString;
```

Comment: Did you mean to have `std::vector<char> stringVector`? As of now, this code doesn't compile.

Comment: "best" is quite ambigious, some common criteria are for example performance, memory-usage or readability

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have a `std::vector<char>` (not a vector of strings) then you can use string constructor that takes a range of characters:

```
std::vector<char> stringVector = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
std::string textString{ stringVector.cbegin()+1,stringVector.cbegin()+4};
```

Comment: Isn't using `cbegin` better here, since we're not modifying `stringVector`?

Comment: @Yun not sure if it is really better here. Though if it doesnt matter, then `cbegin` actually is "better" :P

Comment: That's the point ;)  If something can be `const`, it should be `const`.

Comment: @Yun actually my point was that if the vector was `const` then `begin` would already do "the right thing" and return a const_iterator, though it was the easiest to use `cbegin` as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to concenate each required vector element to the string

```
std::vector<char> stringVector = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};
std::string textString;

textString += stringVector[1];
textString += stringVector[2];
textString += stringVector[3];
```

Comment: `std::vector<string> stringVector = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'};` doesnt compile. I fixed the code in the question. Maybe you want to fix the answer as well